# Struts2 iterator display

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 iterator tag to display value in JSP.

having list called `DepotList`

iterating using following code

```
<s:iterator value="depotList" var="product" status="incr">
  <tr>
     <td><s:property value="depotDescription" /></td>
     <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

it display like below

```
Depot1  0
Depot2  0
Depot3  0
15511   0
```

but I want to display below manner

```
Depot1 0      Depot2 0
Depot3 0      15511  0
```

Any idea how to iterate loop to get out put like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the count property instead of odd/even for 2 or more columns. In the following example would be for 3(module), adjust accordingly.

```
    <s:iterator value="depotList" var="product" status="incr">

   <s:if test="#incr.count%3 == 0 ">
     <tr>
   </s:if>

     <td><s:property value="depotDescription" /></td>
     <td>0</td>

   <s:if test="#incr.count%3 == 0 ">
     </tr>
   </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: thanks it works by modulo 2 and proper condition with 0's and 1's

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem of iteration. But you can manage it by div based layout with css.

Answer (score 0):

You want to goto new table row if it is odd iteration, try something like

```
<s:iterator value="depotList" var="product" status="incr">

   <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true">
     <tr>
   </s:if>

     <td><s:property value="depotDescription" /></td>
     <td>0</td>

   <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd == true">
     </tr>
   </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: it displaying all records in one row